# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" - NullPointerException thrown when trying to fill ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I've been programming in Java for a year or so now at an introductory level, and this is my first time working with `Swing` or any Java GUI. I'm not looking to become an expert with these kinds of GUIs, just trying to create a simple window of buttons with 2 grids that people can use to select a note and a quality for a chord (The program I'm working on rearranges jazz chords.) The segment causing the problem is one where I'm trying to fill an `ArrayList<String>` with different strings depending on which buttons are pressed. Here is the code in question, which is just a test of the GUI:

```
package chordvoicings;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Button[] notes, qualities;
    ArrayList<String> noteArray, qualityArray;

    public GUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 5, 5));

        notes = new Button[12];
        notes[0] = new Button("C");
        notes[1] = new Button("C#/Db");
        notes[2] = new Button("D");
        notes[3] = new Button("D#/Eb");
        notes[4] = new Button("E");
        notes[5] = new Button("F");
        notes[6] = new Button("F#/Gb");
        notes[7] = new Button("G");
        notes[8] = new Button("G#/Ab");
        notes[9] = new Button("A");
        notes[10] = new Button("A#/Bb");
        notes[11] = new Button("B");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
            notes[i].addActionListener(this);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
            add(notes[i]);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        if (command.equals("C")) {
            noteArray.add("C");
        }
        if (command.equals("C#/Db")) {
            noteArray.add("CS");
        }
        if (command.equals("D")) {
            noteArray.add("D");
        }
        if (command.equals("D#/Eb")) {
            noteArray.add("DS");
        }
        if (command.equals("E")) {
            noteArray.add("E");
        }
        if (command.equals("F")) {
            noteArray.add("F");
        }
        if (command.equals("F#/Gb")) {
            noteArray.add("FS");
        }
        if (command.equals("G")) {
            noteArray.add("G");
        }
        if (command.equals("G#/Ab")) {
            noteArray.add("GS");
        }
        if (command.equals("A")) {
            noteArray.add("A");
        }
        if (command.equals("A#/Bb")) {
            noteArray.add("AS");
        }
        if (command.equals("B")) {
            noteArray.add("B");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the error text:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at chordvoicings.GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:52)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I must be doing something very wrong, as I only learned/copied code segments enough to fulfill my purpose (or so I thought.) I've done a lot of research, none of which answered my question, so could anyone offer advice on this matter, whether it's a better way to create an array of `String`s using the `ActionListener` or just a different solution to this problem? I would be happy to provide other code segments of the project I'm working with if they're needed.
Thanks!

Comment: Based on the available code, `noteArray` is never initialised, neither is `qualityArray`

Comment: Lord. I guess I should've checked for obvious errors. I got so caught up in the huge list of exceptions that I never bothered to. Thank you kind sir

Comment: You’ve just about described by life 

Comment: `I got so caught up in the huge list of exceptions` - this is how all Exceptions are reported. All you need to do is look at the first/second line. It will tell you the statement that caused the problem. Then you figure out why that statement is in error.